# Missing news data in GARCH

Tags: regression, garch, macroeconomics

I'm trying to use a GARCH(1,1) model to see if news articles (and their sentiment) about oil have an impact on the volatility of the oil price.

However, in my period of interest, there are a lot of days where there is no news about oil, thus resulting in no values for the  news-variables on multiple days.

Does anybody have any tips on how to tackle this problem? Just missing values on those days? 0's? Or just use the last data value?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Tips: 1) try everything. see. compare. select. 2) An indicator for `no-news` makes sense.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for the reply! Sorry if this is a trivial question: but with indicator you mean a dummy-variable, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My take is that you need to incorporate “no news today” in your model. It contains information, though not the same as a “neutral” article.